# Probability of creating duplicates in a list of size $x$, where range of random integer that can be generated is $1$ to $x^4$

Tags: probability

Title is fairly explanatory

I am wondering what the probability of having duplicate values in a list is if the list has a length of $x$ and is comprised of randomly generated integers in the range of $\{1,\ldots,x^4\}$?

For example a list of size $10$ will have $10$ integers generated in it with each integer being a random number between $1$ and $10,000$.

To put it in python terms would be:

```
def generateList(x):
    return [randint(1, x**4) for i in range(x)]
```

If possible could you also explain how you got to that probability as well?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
1-\prod_{i=1}^{x}(1-\frac{i-1}{x^4}).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Using the previous answer's formula and the inequality $(1-x_1)(1-x_2) \ge (1-(x_1+x_2)$, the probability that no duplicates are drawn is at least $1-x^{-4}\sum_{i=1}^x x$, which is no more than $1-x^{-2}$.